# Reliable way to loop a downloaded video in HTML5?

Tags: html5-video

As far as I can tell, there is no reliable way to loop a video in HTML5. Looping videos are important in medical applications like ultrasounds. I've tried every method I can find.

- The "loop" attribute of the video tag doesn't work in most cases or requires a media server
- Tried setting a handler on the 'ended' event to reset the current time including all the variations of this theme in various blogs

Some have suggested a media server is required to handle partial requests. Hitting the server to restart is not an option. It takes too long. The video needs to loop immediately.

It seems like such a stupid thing not to be able to loop a downloaded video. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work in most cases ? Because it doesn't work (or didn't) on Opera ? can you set a jsfiddle sample that doesn't work so that we can see your problem ?

Comment: <video src="some source" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" /> Try it. Unless your talking to a media server it fails in Chrome and IE. I count that as most cases.

Comment: I spent 6 hours on this before asking this question. Then I find the mime type is not right from the server, sigh... Things work much better with the right mime type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not a very direct answer, but if you look into jPlayer and its loop option here http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-loop you may find some useful tips on how to get it to work across browsers.
Also, if you need cross browser portability, jPlayer is pretty good (I use it a lot for audio, but video should be the same).

Comment: I've tried the "play on ended" method. Doesn't work on Chrome for videos served from non-media servers